# 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf file (Debian)

Tags: debian, resolv.conf

I am not running DNS server on my Debian machine. However, file `resolv.conf` contains the following lines:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net
```

Is it normal to have line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in this file. If not, can I just edit this file and remove it?

I uninstalled bind9.

I have other severs @server4you and never Bind9 was installed by default and resolv.conf does not contain line nameserver 127.0.0.1. I just got a new server @ovh with installed Bind9 which I have uninstalled.

Comment: Why do you want to change it?  Are you experiencing an issue?

Comment: Desktop Debian machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal and strongly recommended if you are running a DNS server on the local host like Bind/DNSMasq, etc.  You usually should point to your DNS server only, and configure any forwards you require within the DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not running a name server? You'll likely find dnsmaq running

```
netstat -tunlp | grep :53
```

Comment: I uninstalled bind9. That's why I ask if this line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` is OK

Comment: If you don't have a local DNS server running on that system, then remove that line.

Comment: @tfegc Ah right important information that should have been in your question. If you have no DNS server listening 127.0.0.1:53 then there is no need for the line.

Comment: When removing nameserver 127.0.0.1 from `etc/resolv.conf` it gets added again with `resolvconf -u`. How can I remove it permanent?